# boolean function uses in c++

Tags: c++, boolean-operations

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>

bool findG( const std::string name)
{
    return name.length() >= 3 && name[0] == 'H'; 
}

bool NotfindG( const std::string name)
{
    return !findG(name); 
}

int main()
{
    std::string name = "agHello";


    if(findG(name)) 
    {
        std::cout << "It found Hello\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "It did not find hello \n";
    }
}
```

What you see a boolean function that returns if it finds the string that is given in the argument.

I understand what the function is doing. What my interest is to know what the activities of the function `NotfindG` in the above code?

```
bool NotfindG( const std::string name)
{
    return !findG(name); 
}
```

I saw someone was using this but to me, the function should work even without the boolean function `NotfindG` (i mean in the else condition). Could you give me some reasoning about why someone would use that?

Comment: Probably a layer of abstraction in case `NotfindG` will ever need to do more than just call `findG` - in that case it would be easier to just change `NotfindG` instead of going through every line of code that calls `findG`

Comment: @zero_field Apart from other typos here  return !findG;  there is also a typo.:) The code does not make sense.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, the code runs perfectly well. You can try first I think. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example code, nothing actually calls `NotFindG`, so indeed there's just no need for it.

A general-purpose `Not*` variation of a bool function is of limited use, but I can come up with a few justifications:

- It does little harm by existing; if a caller feels it's better to use it, then go ahead.
- It could be in a series of similar functions, so even if this particular function doesn't seem necessary it's just a matter of being consistent with some kind of style.
- `FindG` looks specific to some kind of business logic, which means wrapping as much of it as possible may be a good idea. Maybe `NotFindG` is a specific requirement that could theoretically be something other than `FindG`, so it's technically more accurate to call `NotFindG` than `!FindG`. Heck maybe `FindG` is the one that should be removed if this is the case.